# Passing array (member of a struct) to function

Tags: c, arrays, parameters, struct, sizeof

I am attempting to pass, by reference, a 1-D array of characters to a function. Here is the relevant code:

```
void function1();
void function2(struct template *);

struct template{
        char array[11];
};

function1()
{
    struct template myStruct = {0};  //initializing

    function2(&myStruct);
}

function2(struct template *myStruct)
{
    void writeToArray(char array[11]); //locally declaring a function

    writeToArray(myStruct->array);
}

void writeToArray(char array[11])
{
    /*** stuff ****/
}
```

Now, when debugging this code, I get an unexpected result. Once I have entered writeToArray(), I call

```
p sizeof(array)
```

which returns 4. Shouldn't a value of 11 be returned?

I am aware that the "sizeof" for all variables is statically set at compile time. So why is the compiler considering "char array[11]" of writeToArray() to be size==4?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `void writeToArray(char array[11])`, it is actually declaring:
`void writeToArray(char *array)`.

You can find more on this by looking up 'decaying to pointers'.

So when you do `sizeof(array)` you are getting the size of the pointer.

If you want to do maintain this array size, try using `void writeToArray(char (&array)[11])` instead.

This is passing the array by reference then declaring it an array of size 11. It will return the value you are expecting from `sizeof`.

Note: Even if your way did work, you are hard-coding the value 11, so you would be better of just declaring a `const` value and forgetting about `sizeof` altogether. Alternatively, reconsider why you are hard-coding the size.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array as an argument to a function, the starting address of the array is passed to the function. Here the reference is a specified memory location and it occupies 4 bytes of memory on your host system.